# Jquery content replacement not working within my function

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to achieve, and I am nearly there, is the user clicks on a checkbox and it turns green (Checkbox-active class). However, I also want the text/content of the clicked element to change to "Activated" and then reverts back to the original text when clicked again or on a sibling.

```
     $(this).siblings().text(text.replace('active'));
```

The upper code seems to fail. Why?

My HTML Structure

```
  <div class="edit-area-right">
    <div class="font-size">
      <h3>Font Size</h3>
      <div class="checkboxes"> <span class="small">S</span> <span class="medium">M</span> <span class="large">XL</span> </div>
    </div>
```

My Custom Javascript

```
$('.font-size .checkboxes span').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('checkbox-active');
     $(this).siblings().removeClass('checkbox-active');
     $(this).siblings().text(text.replace('activated')); 
});
```

Second attempt: `$(this).siblings.replaceWith( "activated" );`

Comment: Check any DOC regarding `replace()` javascript method. BTW, you didn't provide code regarding variable `text`

Comment: *However, I also want the text/content to change to "Activated"* .. .. and that should be done by `$(this).siblings().text(text.replace('active'));`? So where is `"Activated"` supposed to come from?

Comment: *"is the user clicks on a checkbox and it turns"* - First of all, where is the checkbox..?!

Comment: @PeterKA my second attempt:      

$(this).siblings.replaceWith( "activated" );

Comment: What do you want to change to 'Activated'?

Comment: @TJ I dont want to use checkboxes. I dont need them because I can do the same with just divs and style them as I want

Comment: We have the letter S, M, and XL in the spans there. If I click on one of them then that spans text will be replaced with activated

Comment: `$(this).text('Activated');` should replace either S, M or XL to Activated.

Comment: @MinusFour problem is I dont want the siblings to be affected. Also if the user clicks on the span twice it should revert back to the original content

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use data attributes to hold a copy of the original content of each `span` element. Each click should read from that attribute and replace the span contents for all siblings. A second click of the same span should read from the attribute and replace the contents of the span as show below:

```js
$('.font-size .checkboxes span').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('checkbox-active');
  
  //Get content of clicked span and remove any spaces around it, if any
  var text = $(this).text().trim();
  
  //If current content (before click) is 'Activated' set to default value
  //Otherwise set content to 'Activated'; default content is in `data-txt` attribute
  //Using the ternary operator -- ?:
  $(this).text( text === 'Activated' ? $(this).data('txt') : 'Activated' );
  
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('checkbox-active')
  
  //Set content of all siblings to their default ( data-txt attribute ) values
  .text(function() {
    return $(this).data('txt');
  });
});
```

```css
.checkbox-active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="edit-area-right">
  <div class="font-size">
    <h3>Font Size</h3>
    <div class="checkboxes">
      <span data-txt="S" class="small">S</span> 
      <span data-txt="M" class="medium">M</span> 
      <span data-txt="XL" class="large">XL</span> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

Sources:

1. [**Ternary Operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)
2. [**jQuery.data() | jQuery API Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)
3. [**.text() | jQuery API Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: huh, beat me to this +1 :)

Comment: @PeterKA can you comment your code so that I can learn? I would really appreciate it :D. Isnt data attributes a html5 feature? Does ie8 support it?

Comment: I think I have a bit of issues understanding the second comment. I will try harder :)

Comment: Ok I understand now. Why do you trim spaces? What space?

Comment: `$(this).text( text === 'Activated' ? $(this).data('txt') : 'Activated' );` is equivalent to: `if( text === 'Activated' ) { $(this).text( $(this).data('txt') ); } else { $(this).text( 'Activated' ); }`

Comment: You do not have to use `.trim()`; it is just a precautionary measure.

Comment: @PeterKA  so it is a shorthand. Interesting. I tried something. I tried replacing .text with .append using your method. I append a font-awesome icon instead. Here my jsfiddle and it nearly works http://jsfiddle.net/pcL4auLv/2/

Comment: Please consider using `.html()` instead of `.append()`: http://jsfiddle.net/pcL4auLv/5/

Comment: @PeterKA I will do that. The principle, after what I understood with your method, is the same for all types of content, be it text or html.

Comment: @PeterKA thank you for your time explaining this to me. I accepted your answer as the most helpful. I also thank the others for their help

Comment: Great! Glad I could be of help. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.font-size .checkboxes span').each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).data('text', $(this).text());
    });
  });
```

This code should basically copy whatever the text of your span is holding and save it inside the jQuery object.

```
$('.font-size .checkboxes span').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('checkbox-active');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('checkbox-active');
    $(this).siblings().each(function(index, element) {
       $(this).text($(this).data('text'));
    });
    //Edit to revert to original if double click.
    if($(this).hasClass('checkbox-active')){
      $(this).text('Activated');
    } else {
      $(this).text($(this).data('text'));
    }
});
```

This code is pretty much the same thing you have, the only thing is that it resets their siblings text to its default value, using the stored value by using data().

Here's the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/0xvtrLoz/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with based on your description to get you started.

```
$('.small').data('text', 'S');
$('.medium').data('text', 'M');
$('.large').data('text', 'XL');

$('.font-size .checkboxes span').click(function () {

    $(this).siblings().removeClass('checkbox-active');
    $.each( $(this).siblings(), function(i, value) {
        $(value).text( $(value).data('text') );
    });

    if ( $(this).hasClass('checkbox-active') ) {
        $(this).text( $(this).data('text') );
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass('checkbox-active');
        $(this).text('Activated');
    }
});
```

Comment: check out what happens. The color stays green when deactivating. http://jsfiddle.net/t4saamd8/2/   I will trying to add a removeclass in the else statement

Comment: My mistake. Yeah you probably want to throw in $(this).removeClass('checkbox-active'); in the if statement. Definitely like PeterKA's solution better.